# Adding method which throws exceptions to initialize() in JavaFX controller class

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, tableview

I am trying to initialize a TableView element, and to do so I need to get the data from DB. Method (located in controller class), which takes the data from the DB and returns ObservableList, throws SQLException and ClassNotFoundException. When I put that method in initialize(), i get an error:

> overridden method does not throw 'java.sql.SQLException'

The only way around to make it work was to make a button and link it to that method. But that doesn't populate TableView automatically.
Is there any way to call that method whenever this stage opens, without the whole "button" approach?

Code:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // Link table cells to Rates object
    currencyCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().currencyCodeProperty());
    buyCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().buyRateProperty().asObject());
    sellCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().sellRateProperty().asObject());
}

@FXML
public void populateRates() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObservableList<Rates> rates = RatesDAO.showRates();
        currencyTable.setItems(rates);
        System.out.println(rates);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to implement `Initializable` since JavaFX8. The `FXMLLoader` will look for a method called `initialize()` with no arguments and is void.

```
@FXML
private void initialize() { }
```

Move the two first lines in `polulateRates()` into `initialize()`.

```
ObservableList<Rates> rates = RatesDAO.showRates();
currencyTable.setItems(rates):
```